# Permission denied on /dev/stderr which prevents me to redirect logs to cloudwatch

Tags: docker, nginx, permissions, stdout, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an application which uses nginx which is deployed as a docker container in aws ecs. nginx runs as a different user 'iris' ,same as my application.
my application logs the errors and output to /home/iris/var/log/nginx/access.log, error.log.
Now i need to redirect the logs to /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr so that cloudwatch can stream those log files.
I tried

```
 RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /home/iris/var/log/nginx/access.log \
         && ln -sf /dev/stderr /home/iris/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

in my image file, but stops producing output as i believe the terminal device /dev/stdout is owned by root without write permission for others.
I also tried

```
usermod -a -G sudo iris
```

No luck. Any help would be appreciated.